# Java connect SQLSever

Tags: java, connection

I'm using Eclipe ADT to connect with SQLSever 2008. I had add `sqljdbc4.jar` to my project and I still get error

```
No Suitable Driver For jdbc:microsoft:sqlsever://
```

My code:

```
package ConnectToSQLSever;

import java.sql.*;

public class CreateConnect {

final private static String DB_DRIVER="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
final private static String DB_HOST="ACER-4755";
final private static String DB_PORT="1433";

final private static String DB_NAME="TestDB";
final private static String DB_UID="";
final private static String DB_PWD="";


final private static String DB_URL="jdbc:sqlsever://"+DB_HOST+":"+DB_PORT+"/"+DB_NAME;


private static Connection cnt;

public static Connection getConnection()
{

    try 
    {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
        cnt=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_UID, DB_PWD);
        System.out.println("Connection Successfully");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Connection ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return cnt;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getConnection();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL should be

```
jdbc:sqlserver://ACER-4755:1433;DatabaseName=TestDB
```

Edit: (OP now getting error message as `The TCP/IP connection to the host ACER-4755, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port`)

So you need to do the following

1) Open SQL Server Configuration Manager, and then expand SQL Server 2012 Network Configuration.

2) Click Protocols for InstanceName, and then make sure TCP/IP is enabled in the right panel and double-click TCP/IP.

3) On the Protocol tab, notice the value of the Listen All item.

4) Click the IP Addresses tab: If the value of Listen All is yes, the TCP/IP port number for this instance of SQL Server 2012 is the value of the TCP Dynamic Ports item under IPAll. If the value of Listen All is no, the TCP/IP port number for this instance of SQL Server 2012 is the value of the TCP Dynamic Ports item for a specific IP address.

5) Make sure the TCP Port is 1433.

6) Click OK.

Comment: thank but now i got another error like this:

The TCP/IP connection to the host ACER-4755, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: As the error says, you need to make sure that your sql server is running and listening on port 1433. If server is running then you need to check whether there is some firewall rule rejecting the connection on port 1433.

Comment: @KaJasB, Have you checked whether the database port 1433 is open and not blocked by firewall as the error says?

Comment: sorry but i'm not good with sqlsever please tell me instruction to do it.

Comment: ling.s:
in my command prompt it replied:

'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: @ling.s i use sqlsever 2008 not 2012 please re-edit your answer so that i can follow your instruction.

Comment: @KajasB In the SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols, check that named pipes and tcp/ip are enabled.

If that doesn't work then it may be your firewall blocking it, try this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

This may be useful too: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

Comment: it so hard to configure it. now i close my firewalll to test this connect but it still display that message.

Comment: What is the response now?

Comment: you need to Go to `Start > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`.When it opens Go to

`SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLExpress `. Where you'll find the Protocol TCP/IP, if disabled then Enable it Click on TCP/IP, You'll find its properties.

In this properties Remove All the TCP Dynamic Ports and Add value of 1433 to all TCP Port and restart your SQL Server Services > SQL Server

Comment: refer http://servercomputing.blogspot.in/2012/09/telnet-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file.html for telnet issue

Comment: i'm change my driver to "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver".
and add new Driver to Administrative tool.
so it's working now. thank for your answer but i still can't connect to sqlsever using your method. thank again.

Answer (score 0):

your project include that sqljdbc4.jar.

right click for submenu(when your project highlighting in Eclipse)

Properties -> java build path -> libraliesTab -> Add jar or External jar click

and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have only included sqljdbc4.jar. If you have an older version like sqljdbc.jar also included, then there might be a problem

Comment: no i only include sqljdbc4.jar only. i try it again and again but it still not work.

Comment: @KaJasB, and check your connection string as well. it should be "jdbc:sqlsever://"+DB_HOST+":"+DB_PORT+"\"+DB_NAME, notice after DB_PORT you have entered "/". but it should be "\"

Answer (score 0):

As i know maybe your sqljdbc4.jar is older,change it to a higher, such as sqljdbc6.jar,
  or you make a mistake when you import saljdbc4.jar into your project.

Comment: thank for your comment. but now it not a problem. 
Now my problem is :

The TCP/IP connection to the host ACER-4755, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".